# error message on using apt or apt-get

Tags: 18.04, apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using ubuntu 18 on WSL.

using `apt` for example `sudo apt autoremove` I get error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dns-root-data dnsmasq-base ebtables libdumbnet1 libllvm9 liblxc-common liblxc1 libyaml-0-2 linux-headers-4.15.0-88
  linux-headers-4.15.0-88-generic lxcfs squashfs-tools uidmap xdelta3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  python-doc python-tk
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
```

same thing using `sudo apt install python` for example:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dns-root-data dnsmasq-base ebtables libdumbnet1 libllvm9 liblxc-common liblxc1 libyaml-0-2 linux-headers-4.15.0-88
  linux-headers-4.15.0-88-generic lxcfs squashfs-tools uidmap xdelta3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  python-doc python-tk
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick and dirty solution that has been far too convenient at times, rename a file:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.old
```

Then you can do whatever you need with `apt`, then rename the file back to what it was originally.

Comment: is thee any more permanent solution?

Comment: Not that I've found ... but I don't use WSL very often at all. I try to stick to operating systems that have an "X" at the end of their name 